# How to build the Google Nearby Connection repo on Windows? (preferably using Visual Studio)

Tags: google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I am facing multiple build issues upon building this repo on a Windows machine - https://github.com/google/nearby/tree/main/connections. The idea is to create a Windows UWP app that can leverage this platform, but I could not find instructions on building it for Windows.

Is there any integration guide or a sample app for working with this platform on Windows?

Followed the instructions in this file - https://github.com/google/nearby/blob/main/connections/README.md